# balabolka cannot synthesize the speech class not registered

Tags: windows-10, balabolka

I downloaded free SAPI5 TTS voices from [zero2000](http://www.zero2000.com/free-text-to-speech-natural-voices.html) and when I try to select them (Michaelle, Michelle or Mary, Mike) in Balabolka it throws an error:

```
Cannot synthesize the speech:

Class not registered.
```

[image]

Does anyone know how can I register those classes?

Also, Sam is not even showing in the list of SAPI5 voices.

I am on Win 10 Home:

```
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 20H2
OS build    19042.804
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem with russian TTS (Nikolai). Fixed by adding russian language at Settings -> Speech -> Manage voices -> Add voice
and restarting PC.

Comment: Happened to me with `Microsoft Irina Desktop (Russian (Russia))`. Also was showing `OLE error 80048018`. MS Edge TTS and the voice preview in the Speech settings did not worked for the voice. Windows restart helped.